# Room: @Ignore не работает

Tags: java, android, kotlin, room

Есть класс для `Room` с вложенными классами.
Я получаю поле `var imageUrl: String` из запроса.
После делаю манипуляции с этой ссылкой и получаю эту картинка в байтах и записываю ее в поле `var imageImg: ByteArray`
Я не хочу сохранять это поле в `Room` (слишком много весит и БД не позволяет это сохранить выдавая ошибку  `Row too big to fit into CursorWindow`)
Поэтому я хочу проигнорировать это поле при сохранении в БД.
Вешаю `@Ignore` - все ровно пытается сохранить и вылетает ошибка.
Меняю на `@Transient` - все работает хорошо.
Но поискав в инете инфу, я увидел, что лучше использовать `@Ignore`, а он не игнорирует.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
import androidx.room.Ignore
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName


data class MetadataXX(
    @SerializedName("bgImageUrl")
    var bgImageUrl: String,
    @SerializedName("imageUrl")
    var imageUrl: String,
    @Ignore
    var imageImg: ByteArray,
    @SerializedName("isActive")
    var isActive: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("tallImageUrl")
    var tallImageUrl: String
)
```

Comment: Судя по наличию аннотаций SerializedName - вы не тот Ignore используете. Скорее всего вам надо проверить импорты - должен быть румовский Ignore, а у вас, наверное, Ignore от какой-то либы для парсинга JSON

Comment: Покажите импорты, добавьте их в вопрос. Как подключаете room в проект, используется ли androidx?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил. у меня только 1 Ignore предлгает импортить и он румовский

Comment: @Vadik обновил.

Comment: А разве у сущностей БД не должно быть аннотации [`@Entity`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data)?

Comment: Странно... Может быть, сие баг в либе, хотя и врядли. Попробуйте вот такую аннотацию на конструктор повесить: `@JvmOverloads`. Т.е. типа `data class MetadataXX @JvmOverloads constuctor(`

Comment: @Vadik, судя по примеру из доки - для вложенных объектов она не нужна: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-objects

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогает.

Comment: Однажды я столкнулся с похожей проблемой. Как я понял, на устройстве создаётся своя БД на основе описанной в коде. После внесения изменений в БД SQLite внутренняя БД устройства не изменяется. Поэтому рекомендую вам отчистить все данные на эмуляторе и установить приложение на чистый эмулятор.

Comment: Вам стоит попытаться сделать [минимальный, но самодостаточный пример, демонстрирующий проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Чтобы ее смогли воспроизвести другие участники, чтобы помочь вам. Локализуйте проблему. Например, воспроизводится ли она только внутри @Embedded?

Comment: Возможно, игнорирование для вложенных объектов всё таки просто не поддерживается. Судя по 142 строке [исходников](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/room/room-compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/processor/PojoProcessor.kt) игнорируемые поля обрабатываются только для классов с Entity аннотацией.